# Barplot with stacked time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a number of monthly time series which can be summed (with weights usually but not important here) to get a value for an index.

Here's an excerpt of my data:

```
    01.2009  02.2009  03.2009  04.2009  05.2009  06.2009  07.2009
aaa 321.5743 323.7106 323.9933 326.1296 329.6482 328.3287 328.9571
bbb 322.0770 324.4646 324.8730 327.1978 331.2504 329.3969 330.0252
ccc 324.7473 326.7894 328.0146 329.2398 330.4964 331.3447 332.1929
```

I am learning to use `ggplot2` and I'd like to get a stacked barplot plot, i.e. at each point of time on the horizontal axis, there's a three-colored bar with a value `aaa+bbb+ccc` so that it represents time-evolving contributions to the index of each of the series.

I've also generated a vector `dates` of type

```
"2009-01-15" "2009-02-15" "2009-03-15"
```

Here's what I tried until now

```
plot.data <- melt(as.data.frame(cbind(t(data), dates)), id.vars="dates")
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=factor(dates), y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

However, this seems to use the time series name, e.g. `aaa`,  as an additional factor and so I don't have anything stacked. I am sure I'm just doing something wrong. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use ggplot2, You should put your data in the long format but you need before to add rownames as a new column. This column will be used to stack your bars for each date.

Here my code

```
## read data
dat <- read.table(text='   01.2009  02.2009  03.2009  04.2009  05.2009  06.2009  07.2009
aaa 321.5743 323.7106 323.9933 326.1296 329.6482 328.3287 328.9571
bbb 322.0770 324.4646 324.8730 327.1978 331.2504 329.3969 330.0252
ccc 324.7473 326.7894 328.0146 329.2398 330.4964 331.3447 332.1929')
## add rownames as index column and put data in long format
dat.m <- melt(cbind(index=rownames(dat),dat))
## convert variable to a valid date to get pretty axes
dat.m$variable <- as.Date(paste0('15.',gsub('X','',dat.m$variable)),format='%d.%m.%Y')

library(ggplot2)
## plot it!
ggplot(dat.m) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=variable,y=value,fill=index),
           stat='identity')
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. I've been fighting this for a couple of hours now. Thank you!